# Why does touching the Rx line cause my XBee to reset?

Tags: uart, troubleshooting, xbee

I have an XBee, XB3-24Z8CM-J, in MicroPython mode, autostarts script on boot, 115220 baud, UART is enabled on Pin 4 & 5.

The issue is that when I touch pin 4 (Rx) while the script is running the XBee resets, causing the script to reset. I monitored the Rx line with a logic analyzer and found that when the pin is tapped with my tweezers there is a spike in voltage on the Rx line, anywhere from 300 mV-1.3V. It's enough to make my logic analyzer interpret it as a logic high, and every time, exactly 5 seconds later, the XBee resets itself.

I attempted to pull the line low with 20 kΩ, 10 kΩ, and 5 kΩ. It made the spikes lower but not low enough, besides, this was just to see if I could delete them, disregarding if it affected the UART comms.

There are two different applications that I tested this in, in one fashion the UART lines are floating. In the other fashion they are connected to a Raspberry Pi, but the primary purpose of the XBee is that it toggles a relay to cut power to the Pi itself, so the UART lines are connected to a Pi with no power.

Comment: Have you considered that ESD might be the problem?

Comment: Well there is a charge or discharge of something going on. Whether its a Pi UART line or a finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a 100K Pull-Up Resistor to the XB's 3.3V fixed the issue.